# Redis-om-spring+springboot3+jdk 17 giving this err "beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'redisJSONKeyValueTemplate' available

Tags: spring-boot, redis, redis-om-spring

I am facing a strange issue while running this this example https://github.com/redis-developer/redis-om-spring-skeleton-app . I am using Redis-om-spring+springboot3+jdk 17 . Project is building fine while running the spring boot application (SkeletonApplication.java) but getting the below exception. Any help would be appreciated.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'redisJSONKeyValueTemplate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:892) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1318) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1663) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:127) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at com.redis.om.skeleton.SkeletonApplication.main(SkeletonApplication.java:85) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]

2023-02-08T10:49:14.918-05:00 ERROR 51783 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repo in com.redis.om.skeleton.SkeletonApplication required a bean named 'redisJSONKeyValueTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

My build.gradle is this :

````
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
compileOnly {
extendsFrom annotationProcessor
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
implementation "com.redis.om:redis-om-spring:0.6.4"
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0"
}

test {
useJUnitPlatform()
}```


Rest of the code is exactly same as this repo : https://github.com/redis-developer/redis-om-spring-skeleton-app
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated the skeleton app for Spring Boot 3.x - let me if works for you.

Comment: Sure tnx will let you know.

Comment: Hello BSB, thanks for the help. Is there any ETA for releasing this as a stable maven repo version?

Comment: @Sukh in the next few days, getting a few more bug fixes in.

Comment: We are planning to use this for our current project (Redis Enterprise+ReadisSearch+ redim-om-spring + spring boot 3). We need to make a decision on this as it involves money (Redis Enterprise on cloud). Can we use the snapshot 0.8.0 if it does not have any blocker bug(s)? We need to deliver the project within a month or so.

Comment: Hello @BSB, Can you please have a look at the above question? Really appreciate it, we need to make a decision. Is 0.8.0snapshot version good for use in production?

Comment: @sukh come join us on the Discord server and I can give you folks some direct assistance. https://discord.com/invite/redis also accept the answer above if the updates worked :-)

Comment: Sure i just joined and accepted the answer as well.